# table which isnt in another table or in but with condition

Tags: php, mysql

Take 30 questions from the `questions` table which doesn't contain in `quiz_participant_answer` table / or contain but not all rows have `is_correct` equal to 1.

**Questions table**

[image]

**Question_participant_answer_table**

[image]

```
DB::table("questions")->select('*')->whereNotIn('question_id',
        function($query) use  ($user) {

        $query->select('question_id')->from('quiz_participant_answer')->where('user_id',$user->user_id)->where('question_id',$question_id);

    })->get();
```

Here my query. But I don't know how to check for `is_correct`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT q.question_id, q.question_text, q.question_language
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN quiz_participant_answer qpa ON q.question_id = qpa.question_id
                                     AND qpa.is_correct = 0
WHERE COALESCE(qpa.question_id, 0) = 0 
/* AND another conditions */
```

Comment: I isn't what I need . It gives me first not correct user answers joined with questions ?

Comment: @JKSDS ??? Why "first"??? Please look at ALL records returned by the query, not the first one only.